# Difference between Contents of two SVN Branches

Tags: git, bash, shell, svn, scripting

I want to compare two svn branches http://.../Br1 and http://.../Br2 such that script refers to a text file for names of files to check in Branches and shows a result that only gives missing file names in Br1 or Br2. I came across `svn diff` but it is not helping. Then I came across these commands:

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
```

```
diff <(cd folder1 && find . | sort) <(cd folder2 && find . | sort)
```

```
diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt
```

But all these scripts can tun on checked out SVN repo, I'm looking for a way to run these commands on a http://svn_repo_link/ and a script that can refer a text file for names of files to check in Br1 and Br2, then provide names of files missing in Br1 or Br2 with directory structure.

Comment: Did you try to use `svn diff --summarize` ?

Comment: @IvanZhakov yes i tried that, it gives a huge list of files, however all I want is to check if same java files exist in both svn branches or not and if any file is missing then it gives name of that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think running `svn diff --summarize` and grepping output should help:

```
svn diff --summarize http://.../Br1 and http://.../Br2 | grep "A   "
```

Comment: What if we only want to check *.java files, what should be grep "" ?

Comment: I tried it, but I'm not sure how to read the results, can you please give an example and elaborate that how to read the output.

Comment: `svn diff http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.8.x http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.9.x --summarize | grep "^A .*\.java"`

Comment: I tried this: `svn diff http://172.16.1.57/CRM/MFS/Mobiquity/branches/Mobiquity_v4.8/ http://172.16.1.57/CRM/MFS/Mobiquity/branches/Mobiquity_v4.9/ --summarize | grep " .*\.java"` Got this result: `M http://172.16.1.57/CRM/MFS/Mobiquity/branches/Mobiquity_v4.8/Code/MavenCode/Root‌​Txn/somtel/src/main/java/com/mmoney/interfaces/Alcatel432UrlConnection.java I actually want to compare if java files present in v4.8 are also present in v4.9`